# Tips and tricks for emacs' viper-mode and the likes

Tags: vim, emacs

Basically, I really like vi[m]'s key-bindings, but not the rest of the editor. I really dislike emacs key-bindings, but *like* the rest of the editor.

[`viper-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) seems like the best of both worlds, but it's not perfect..

What vim features did you miss in emacs (and more importantly, how did you get them back)? What config-tweaks did you do to make viper-mode nicer to use?

As a start: I really missed vim's visual-selection mode.. [vimpulse](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vimpulse) adds this to emacs!

Comment: I know _exactly_ how you feel. Emacs keybindings are horrendous, everything else is awesome.

Comment: Can someone explain what the "rest of the editor" means?  I like the key-binding's in vim a lot too!

Comment: @Bart http://upsilon.cc/~zack/blog/posts/2008/11/from_Vim_to_Emacs_-_part_2/ explains it better than I could

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, VIM/VI has always had the `:set nu` feature to show line numbers along-side the lines themselves. By default, emacs only had `line-number-mode` which showed the line-number of the current line in the mode-line (not the same thing).

To fix that, I always found [linum.el](http://stud4.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/linum/linum.el) pretty useful. Starting with the upcoming emacs 23, the `linum` mode would be included in the standard distribution. But for emacs <= 22, one still needs to install it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I also miss the incremental search with / and ? . Something like 
what is posted here first in the TODO section.
http://common-lisp.net/project/vial/darcs/extended-viper/vimlike.el

If anyone can provide it, it would be great. Jurta ?

Comment: Just remap / and ? to call `isearch-forward` and `isearch-backward` in the viper keymap, with something like:

`(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "/" 'isearch-forward)`

..and similar for `?`.

This gives incremental search, but behaves like the Emacs search rather than vi (so `n` and `N` don't work as expected, but these can probably be modified in a similar way if you're so inclined)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [my version of the emacs starter kit](https://github.com/m7d/emacs-starter-kit). It is totally customized for heavy (symbiotic) use of emacs and vi/vim (via viper and vimpulse) together.